# Как частично отключить Jade в nodejs?

Tags: node.js, jade, javascript

Меня устраивает работа этого шаблонизатора, но мне очень неудобно писать html по правилам jade. Можно ли как-то оставить {{переменные}}, но вместо синтаксиса jade использовать обычную html верстку? Если нет, то посоветуйте, в каком шаблонизаторе это можно.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему тем, что перешел на ejs шаблонизатор.